# TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined when calling Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I had a clound function defined in `index.js` file like below:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.newMessage = functions.database
  .ref('/privateMessages/{userA}/{userB}/{message}')
  .onWrite((snap, context) => {
    const original = snap.after.val();
    const userA = context.params.userA;
    const userB = context.params.userB;
    const message = context.params.message;
    console.log('debug', userA, userB, original, message);
    return ;
  });
```

When the function execution started, I always got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at resourceToInstanceAndPath (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/database.js:154:26)
    at dataConstructor (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/database.js:122:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:89:32)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
```

The structure of firebase realtime database is like below. If there is any new message created between existing userA and userB, a new message entry will be created. If it's a new chat session, a new userA and newB will be created as well as the message. 
[image]

package.json in functions folder is like below:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the contents of your package.json file. The error doesn't seem related to your code at all.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. I just added package.json in the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a very old firebase-functions module.  The latest is 3.2.0.  You can see there was the [same bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/416) reported a while back, but the issue has been closed.

(Your firebase-admin is quite old as well.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Doug! After updating both to the latest, I am not seeing any error in the log.

Comment: One more quick question Doug, when a new chat session is started, userA and userB would be newly created, is there any way we could know if they are new or existing ones? Thanks!

Comment: If you have another question, please post it separately.